# MS Access handling #error

Tags: ms-access

Sometimes when I have a field that has #Error such as a divide by 0, is there a way to perform an isError() or something similar? Sometimes it's not always clear when a mistake has been made, which means I have to go back through a bunch of queries to find where some div/0 error has taken place, since usually the errors occur silently. I'd like to be able to explicitly look for #Iserror so I can locate it when it occurs.

e.g. `SELECT sourcetable.fieldname INTO desttable IN '\\path\database.mdb'FROM sourcetable;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For division by zero, you should be trapping in a different way ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/avoiding-divide-by-zero-errors-in-access-HA001055073.aspx )

```
=IIf([Divisor]=0,Null,[Dividend]/[Divisor])
```

It is not unusual to use IsError with a reference to a subform:

```
=IIf(IsError([Form].[Subform]![SummedControl]),0,[Form].[Subform]![SummedControl])
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that; but there are times when different things result in the same #error and it'd be nice to trap that so I can go back and implement the code correctly.

Comment: Not everything that is an error IsError. I will add an example that is.

Comment: **Provided link does not exist**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following :

```
=IIF([Divisor] IS NULL OR [Divisor]=0, Null, [Dividend]/[Divisor])
```